# Не работает Django translation

Tags: python, django, debian

Есть вьюха переключающая язык на русский:

```
class SetLangRuView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        activate('ru')
        request.session['lang'] = 'ru';
        return redirect('main_page')
```

Проблема следующая: на машине, где идёт разработка, проблем с переключением нет. Машина на Win 8.1, VPS, где находится продакшен, стоит Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 и вот на продакшене переключение языков не работает.
И вот вопрос, как это исправить? Русскую локаль уже установил, ребутнул, проблема не пропала. Полный путь к папке locale прописал, ситуация не изменилась.
Вот пример работы djsngo shell на win8.1

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate, get_language,ugettext as _
>>> activate('ru')
>>> _("Hellow")
u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'
>>>
```

А вот пример с продакшена на debian:

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate, get_language,ugettext as _
>>> activate('ru')
>>> _("Hellow")
u'Hellow'
```

Из чего следует, что проблема не проекте, а где то в системе.
Может кто то уже лечил подобное?

Comment: Дайте угадаю: вы забываете выполнить `activate` во всех других вьюхах, да?

Comment: Нет, activate выполняю на каждый get запрос.